# How to get debugging of an App Engine application working?

Tags: python, eclipse, debugging, google-app-engine, pydev

I've got 10+ years in C/C++, and it appears Visual Studio has spoilt me during that time. In Visual Studio, debbuging issimple: I just add a breakpoint to a line of code, and as soon as that code is executed, my breakpoint triggers, at which point I can view a callstack, local/member variables, etc.

I'm trying to achieve this functionality under App Engine. I assume that is possible?

All the searching I've done to this point has led me to using Pydev in Eclipse. As best I can tell, I am successfully launching my simple 'hello world' program in Debug mode.

But the IDE doesn't even seem to have an option to set a breakpoint? I must be missing something.

I've googled long and hard about this, but am having no luck. Most results trace back to the same old threads that don't deal directly with my issue.

Can anyone shed some light on how you get basic debugging setup using Pydev/Eclipse with App Engine?

Alternatively, if there's an easier way to debug App Engine than using Pydev/Eclipse, I'd love to hear about it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact setting a breakpoint in eclipse is very easy. You have two options:
In the grey area next to your line numbers, doubleclick or right mouseclick -> toggle breakpoint.

Comment: Embarrassingly, that was exactly the problem. The rest of my setup was working perfectly.

Thanks for your help.